# Selenium error org.openqa.selenium.Rectangle

Tags: selenium

I am running a Selenium code in my Intellij Idea and this is the error I am getting.

The error details :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Rectangle

```
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
```

Also tried to import `org.openqa.selenium.Rectangle` but couldn't

Comment: Why you couldn't import said class? What is the error on importing?

Comment: If you're using Maven, please add contents of `pom.xml`

Comment: For importing the error is "Cannot resolve symbol Rectangle"

Comment: Are you using a maven project.

Comment: Yes, maven project

Comment: Please add your maven `pom.xml` file in the question.